# How many different ways to reorder $(1,2,...,n)$ into a sequence with certain restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics

I want to know how many different ways there are to reorder $(1,2,...,n)$ into a sequence not beginning in $n$, nor ending in $1$, nor with two adjacent entries having a step size of $-1$.
For example, if $n=5$, $(4,2,5,1,3)$ is allowed but $(4,5,1,3,2)$ is not.

Comment: Why is 4,2,5,3,1 allowed if the sequence can't end with 1?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland fixed, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Neither is allowed. The first one ends with 1. Just out of curiosity: why such restriction?

Comment: @Heimdall fixed that just now. It is a question regarding $m$-cycles in the alternating group that can be obtained from a certain algorithm. I just rephrased the problem.

Comment: This seems to match [OEIS sequence A000757](https://oeis.org/A000757)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the answer might indeed be $a(n+1)$ with respect to $a(n)$ in [OEIS/A000757](https://oeis.org/A000757) . Will investigate. Thanks!